# Logo image wont show in the navbar (both png and SVG)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a logo on the navigation bar, but I get the alt text instead. This is the section of my navbar:

```
<a class="navbar-left" href="/"><img alt"IFB AMPDB" src"{% static 'icons/logo_IFB.svg' %}"></a>
```

(that src is Django Syntax for the files, and it is not the problem. If i repeat it below in the document, it works fine.)

What else I tried:

- Originally I was going for class="navbar-brand", but changing it wasn't helpful.
- I have tried linking to other images(even from external links), and still no show. So that wasn't the problem.
- Have also tried adding the following code, but I only got a bigger Alt text:

  ```
  style="display: inline-block; height:38px; margin-top: 5px"
  ```

EDIT:

Solution pointed by Drinkin People: there was an equal sign missing in the 'src' tag.

Comment: have you tried putting the equals signs eg. src="your-image-path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the equals signs after the `src` and `alt` in your image tag.

```
<a class="navbar-left" href="/"><img alt="IFB AMPDB" src="{% static 'icons/logo_IFB.svg' %}"></a>
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** I don't believe I spent hours trying struff and it was only an equal sign missing...